# Why can't a branch name contain the 'hash' (#) char at the begining?

Tags: git, workflow, naming-conventions, git-branch, git-checkout

This one

```
git checkout -b #1-my-awesome-feature
```

creates error

```
error: switch `b' requires a value
```

escaping it with backslash or wrapping it in quotes will work

```
git checkout -b \#1-my-awesome-feature
```

but strange enough this

```
git branch #1-my-awesome-feature
```

will **not** produce any error and if you check if it is created with

```
git branch --all
```

there is no branch.

If hash char is not in the first position of the branch name, branch will be **created**.

```
git branch feature-#1
```

Executing `git branch`

```
feature-#1
* master
```

So my question is how hash (#) char is 'translated' in terminal and why it is not working when it is at first place?

Thanks!

Comment: Platform is important.  This will most likely work on Windows.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`#` means a comment is starting (atleast in a linux shell). So

```
git checkout -b #1-my-awesome-feature
```

becomes:

```
git checkout -b
```

and throws error that `b` option requires a value.

As shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190139/232167), you can solve this by escaping the `#` with a `\` or by putting the name in single/double quotes:

```
git checkout -b \#1-my-awesome-feature
git checkout -b "#1-my-awesome-feature"
git checkout -b '#1-my-awesome-feature'
```

Comment: One might also note that `#` _is_ a valid branch name, it just needs to be quoted or escaped. `git branch '#'` or `git checkout -b '#'` works just fine, although it would of course be impractical to name branches this way for the reasons listed in the answer above.